# Displaying a URL on the address line of the URL bar

Tags: wordpress, url, browser, html5-canvas, public-html

I am fairly new at this so forgive my ignorance.

I have a two word press sites that I maintain. www.example1.com and www.example2.org. The example2.org site's domain name points to https://example1.com/example2

When people reference example2.org, I want them to see example2.org not example1.com/example2. And any subsequent pages, I don't want the example1.com site to show up.

I haven't found any way to do this and perhaps it cannot be done.

In cpanel, the example2/index.php is off the example1/public_html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Who is your hosting provider? This has nothing to do with wordpress. Your hosting provider must fix this for you in case they don't provide a tool to set up this virtual host (point a domain to a specific folder)

Comment: This is something you can set in cPanel. Can you post your .htaccess for the example1/public_html folder? Also look in your cPanel at domain names and see if there's any forwarding there.

Comment: Siteground is my hosting provider. @DanielAcevedo Is what I want to do is to create a virtual host?

Comment: @HowardE Is forwarding what I want to do? I wamt to simply change the address bar. Here is my .htaccess
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ListeningToGod/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ListeningToGod/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
 Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF

Comment: @HowardE - Sorry. That was my .htaccess for example2/public_html. Example1 is too big to include in this file. How do I attach a file to a comment? Sorry again for my ignorance!

Comment: Add it to your question

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an Addon domain trough Cpanel.

[Siteground documentation](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/addon-domains/)